# getting compilation error in binary search implementation

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I am implementing binary search algorithm , but i am facing return statement issue.Here is my method **binarySearch()** implementation

```
  public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int n, int x) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = n - 1;

        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if (a[mid] == x) {
                return mid;
            } else if (a[mid] < x) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: add a return statement at last  for "no match found case"

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that this method is called on an array that does not have the value.

You can

```
return 0;
```

at the end of the method call. Or...

```
throw new RuntimeException("Value not found in array");
```

Whichever is right for this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not return all the paths.

```
  public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int n, int x) {

    int start = 0;
    int end = n - 1;
    int result = 0; // Or something you define yourself for not found case

    while (start <= end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (a[mid] == x) {
            result = mid;
        } else if (a[mid] < x) {
            start = mid + 1;
        } else {
            end = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```